# Using Laravel helper functions when unit testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-4

I am testing a class I made that uses a helper function.  The function I'm testing looks like:

```
public function upload(UploadedFile $file)
{
    $file = $file->move(base_path() . '/temp');
    $file = new FileSystemPicture($file);

    return $file;
}
```

When I run the tests and it hits the helper function it says:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function make() on a non-object
```

I have tracked the helper function down to be the following code:

```
function base_path($path = '')
{
    return app()->make('path.base').($path ? '/'.$path : $path);
}
```

I know that I'm getting the error because the "app" hasn't been created because I'm only testing the my class, not the whole application.  Are there other effective ways to get the root directory of my project or is there a way to force the "app" to load so it can be used in this function?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had this problem, solved making sure that:

1. My test class extended TestCase.
2. If my test class had a `setUp()` method, it called `parent::setUp()`

app_path() and similar functions worked after that.

Comment: That's alright for integration tests, but for the unit tests you need a way to mock the helper function.

Comment: `parent::setUp()` should be called before any helper methods are called

Comment: To be clear, the test class should extend `Tests\TestCase`, not `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to mock helper functions that use `app()` function in a complete isolation from laravel environment. Considering that your package has `illuminate/support` dependency you could do something like this:

```
<?php

    class Test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
    {
        protected function mockApplication(array $methods = [])
        {
            return $this->getMock('Illuminate\Foundation\Application', $methods);
        }

        public function testHelperFunction()
        {
            $appMock = $this->mockApplication(['make']);

            \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::setFacadeApplication($appMock);

            $testPath = "my/path";
            $myPath = "otherPath";

            $expectedValue = "{$testPath}/{$myPath}";

            $appMock->expects($this->once())
                    ->method('make')->with('path.base')
                    ->will($this->returnCallback(function () use ($testPath) {
                        return $testPath;
                    }));

            $this->assertSame($expectedValue, base_path($myPath));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue, and my solution is to wrap the whole helpers.php contents with

```
if (!file_exists('newFunction')) {
```

This should prevent the attempt at re-declaring the functions after the first test case has executed.